# How do i make my discord bot reply to a certain user always with the same string?

Tags: python, discord, bots

made my own discord bot using py and trying to solve the issue in the title.

This is my current code for responses

```
def get_response(message: str) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()

    if p_message == 'hello':
        return ''

    if p_message == 'alex':
        return ''

    if p_message == 'benji':
        return ''

    if message == 'roll':
        return str(random.randint(1, 6))

    if p_message == '!help':
        return '`This is a help message that you can modify.`'

    if p_message == '-':
        return ''

    if p_message == 'aja':
        return ''

    if p_message == 'christian':
        return ''
```

This is where i call my responses. And execute the code from above

```
import discord
import responses
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# @client.event                               
# async def on_message(message):
#     if message.author.id == 195251214307426305:   
#         await message.channel.send("")

# @client.event                               
# async def on_message(message):
#     if message.author.id == 305280287519145984:   
#         # Sending a message to the channel that the user is in.
#         await message.channel.send("")

def run_discord_bot():
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" ({channel})')

        if user_message[0] == '?':
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message, user_message, is_private=False)

    TOKEN=""
    with open("token.txt") as file:
        TOKEN = file.read()
    
    
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Tried using msg.author.id and its unknown now. More then that i was sadly stunned by this issue and found no solutions online

Comment: Please add more information, else nobody can help you. Maybe the functions that call ```get_response```

Comment: Furthermore you could use a dict instead of many ifs

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the discord libary, so this could be a solution to your problem

```py
import discord                              #dependencies

client = discord.Client()                   #create a client object

@client.event                               #bind the function
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == 398238482382:   #check for id
        await message.channel.send("Hey")   #send 'hey' to channel where the message was written

client.run(yout_token)                      #starts the bot
```

Comment: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message ?

Comment: added my code where i call the function

Comment: So just tried my code i wrote in my answer and everything works fine for me

Comment: Try to only run my code first and add yours step by step